# perl using subroutine as argument of a foreach

Tags: perl, foreach, subroutine, ref

```
my %number_words = hash_a_file($_);
foreach my $key ( keys %number_words ) {
    ++$word_list{$key};
}
```

This is working but I would like to avoid using the intermediate variable
like this

```
foreach my $key ( keys hash_a_file($_) ) {
    ++$word_list{$key};
}
```

I tried to use refs but still failed. Any way to do this ? Thanks !

Comment: what does it fail with?

Comment: It fails because keys are unique. `%word_list` will count only 1 for each key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is, a subroutine doesn't return a hash. It returns a list. In your original code, it only becomes a hash when you store it in a hash variable.

But there are other ways to create a hash from a list. You can create an anonymous hash and then de-reference it. It's ugly, but it works.

```
# Inner braces create an anonymous hash.
# Outer braces de-reference that into a "real" hash
foreach my $key ( keys %{ { hash_a_file($_) } } ) {
    ++$word_list{$key};
}
```

**Update:** To back up Borodin's comment, I should add that if this code was presented to me in a code review, I'd suggest rewriting it to use an explicit hash variable as your original code does.

Comment: This answers the question in probably the best way possible, but I think the OP's original code is much clearer, and no more wasteful. I would guess that `hash_a_file` builds a hash and then does `return %hash` which converts it into a list. It is inefficient to do this and then convert it back into another hash, and it would be far better to `return \%hash` as in **zdim's** answer, which avoids this double conversion.

Comment: A better solution (if changing `hash_a_file` is out of the question) than needlessly creating a hash is to use `pairkeys` from List::Util.

Answer (score 1):

Return a hashref, so that you can form a valid argument for `keys` (instead of a list)

```
sub hash_a_file { return { a => 1, b => 2 } }

foreach my $key ( keys %{ hash_a_file() } ) {
    say $key
}
```

Comment: Thanks but can't modify hash_a_file. Dave Cross solution works fine anyway.